# Problems with angular strap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I went to the Angular Strap and took the scripts right off of the website

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/v2.3.2/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/v2.3.2/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
```

I added https: since I am running these without a server.  However, I am getting 404's.  Not sure why?  I am using  **angular 1.4.6**  which seems to be what is modeled.

Comment: you are not the only one.. 404 here as well. not sure this is the right place for this question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the urls are:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.3.2/angular-strap.min.js

And

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.3.2/angular-strap.tpl.min.js

See: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-strap

Comment: Just in case you can't see the difference, `v2.3.2` -> `2.3.2`